# WordPress Twilio Webhook JSON issue

Tags: wordpress, twilio, webhooks, twilio-php

Struggling to find an answer to this problem.

I have a WordPress web site and have written a simple webhook to be called from Twilio and return a message.

In Twilio I am using a Studio Flow to call the web hook. Everything works perfectly until it comes time to read the callback data from the trigger.

My webhook is this:

```
function register_receive_message_route() {
  register_rest_route('receivedx/v1', 'recvsms', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'trigger_receive_sms',
    ));
}

function trigger_receive_sms($from) {
  header ('Content-Type:application/json');
  return '{"Message":"Thank you for accepting this position.","From":"From MCC","Body":"Hello"}';
}
```

When I hit my webhook url it returns the JSON string as expected like so:

```
"{\"Message\":\"Thank you for accepting this position.\",\"From\":\"From MCC\",\"Body\":\"Hello\"}"
```

however when it gets to Twilio it is being corrupted and looks like this:

```
"body": "\"{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"Thank you for accepting this position.\\\",\\\"From\\\":\\\"From MCC\\\",\\\"Body\\\":\\\"Hello\\\"}\""
```

Twilio then gives me an error telling me "Body: Failure sending message: Message body is required."

There is nothing special about my widget and after many days chatting to the Twilio team they assure me that my flow is setup correctly.

I have tried doing a replace on \\ with \ however it still shows the same when it gets to Twilio.

I have tried the same webhook on 3 different WordPress installations all with the same result. I am starting to thing that Twilio are doing something with it when it get's returned.

Has anyone seen this behavior coming out of WordPress before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by NOT encoding the data to JSON prior to sending to Twilio.

Simply create an array for what you want to send and return that, Twilio Studio will then encode it prior to processing it.

EG:

$message['message'] = "This is a message";
$message['moredata'] = "This is more data";
return $message

You can then retrieve the results from a widget using {{widget.<>.parsed.message}} etc...

Hope this helps someone.